# Which KeyBoard / KeyBoard Layout will be most suitable for haskell programming? Does haskell has all Math Symbols as functions?

Tags: haskell, emacs, unicode, keyboard, symbols

As an absolute beginner in haskell, I am continuously reading various articles, pdfs , tutorials on haskell. Most of the examples / sample codes include Math Characters. Even for a common task of typing

->

I have to type:   - & >

The fact is I don't know how to type Math Characters in emacs (I am using for practising haskell coding). My current Keyboard Layout is 'English US'.

Is there any specific keyboard or keyboard layout which is most suitable for entering the math symbols (for haskell programming)?

Does haskell has all Math Symbols as functions? My current assumption is that haskell must be supporting all Math Symbols as functions.

e.g. +, - ,/, * etc.

[Unicode Math Symbols](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/symbols/select.html)
Note: These notations are seen in many haskell papers.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difficulty is, exactly. If the → character is inconvenient to type, then -> should work just as well. Since both - and > are both found on a US keyboard (and one of them is shifted), it is possible to type -> in any editor using just three keystrokes. Are you asking if there is a keyboard that allows you to type → or -> using just one or two keystrokes?

Comment: Also, does *what* support all math symbols?

Comment: Many papers are typeset with the tool lhs2TeX - http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex - the code examples are not in themselves valid Haskell syntax when printed in the paper (lhs2TeX is a preprocessor). You certainly don't need an extended keyboard. There is a package on Hackage for Unicode symbols by Roel van Dijk if you must have them in code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not have to use the fancy unicode symbols you see in papers--in place of → you can write `->` and so on for each special character. Given this, a normal US Qwerty layout is perfectly find for Haskell.

However, if you find the → style easier to read (but obviously *not* easier to type), you can have Emacs display code with those symbols instead. This is entirely cosmetic, like syntax highlighting: even though you see a →, the source code still has a `->` and that's still what you type. You can enable this as so:

```
(setq haskell-font-lock-symbols t)
```

This symbol mode might make some of your indentation look a little odd. However, I've been using it for a while and have had no problems at all. I certainly like looking at my code more when it uses pretty symbols in place of ASCII surrogates.

So you still type <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> but it just looks prettier.

However, sometimes you *do* want fancy symbols like Greek letters. For example, if you're implementing an algorithm from a paper, it might make sense to keep the variable names the same. For this, you can use Emacs's TeX input mode via `C-\` and entering `TeX`. This will, for example, allow you to type `\lambda` and get a `λ`. To see the full list of symbols you can type, run `M-x describe-input-method` and then enter `TeX`.

Finally: Haskell *does* support all the "math symbols" like + and - as operators. In fact, any identifier made up of these characters is automatically infix. So you can actually define your own operators. You could write something like:

```
a +++ b = a * a + b * b
```

and then you would be able to use the `+++` function in an infix position, like any other operator. I believe that Haskell determines which characters are "operator characters" by looking at its Unicode category, meaning you can define (and I actually have defined) operators like `×`.

In summary: you do not need any special symbols for Haskell code--it can all be ASCII. You can make Emacs render ASCII Haskell code *with* those symbols if you find them easy to read, and you can actually type them using the TeX input mode.

Answer (score 6):

Most Haskell code uses only the standard set of ASCII characters, although Unicode is supported for operators and function names (and GHC supports using Unicode for syntactically reserved tokens, such as using `→` for `->` and `∷` for `::`, with [`-XUnicodeSyntax`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.10.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#unicode-syntax)).  To quote [the Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-150002.1):

> Haskell uses the Unicode [[2](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellli3.html#Xunicode)] character set. However, source programs are currently biased toward the ASCII character set used in earlier versions of Haskell.

So I'm typically typing <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to get the arrow anyway.  The "prettified" syntax you find in papers is not generally used in actual code, at least in my experience (but I am admittedly not super widely read in Haskell code).  For instance, in papers, [the `++` operator for appending lists](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) is sometimes typeset with the two plus signs overlapped, and I've seen [the `<*>` operator for applicative functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--62-) typeset as `⍟`, a circled star operator.  But I've never seen either in actual Haskell code (the former isn't even a real character), and they aren't defined in the base libraries.  You very often see `→` in place of `->` in papers, and that's supported with `-XUnicodeSyntax`; but again, I've never seen that in actual code, although I'd be less surprised.

There's no keyboard layout that I know of which has real support for all of Unicode, or even just the math symbols (other than just supporting entering in raw hex codes).  However, there are input modes for editors which might be handy.  For instance, there's [RFC 1345](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1345.txt), which defines two-character sequences for a variety of useful characters, and which can *e.g.* be enabled in Emacs with <kbd>C-\</kbd> and selecting `rfc1345`.  Another example is [the mode that Emacs uses for editing Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php?n=Docs.UnicodeInput) ([a dependently typed programming language](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php)), where LaTeX(ish) escapes are translated into Unicode characters.

In short, the answer is that the most suitable keyboard layout is whatever you're most familiar with.  There's nothing particularly special about Haskell's character usage which necessitates anything different.

Answer (score 1):

I know there's a Dvorak style made for [programming](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) but it seems that learning a new keyboard layout would be harder than simply building up muscle memory for the new key combinations you have to hit.